# Qt OpenCV application doesn't run on Raspberry Pi display

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have built a Qt application in C++ that utilizes OpenCV and runs on a Raspberry Pi. For some reason I cannot get this application to run directly on the Raspberry Pi's display.

The application runs fine if I send the display to a remote xserver, but if I try and run it and display it on the xserver running on the Pi I get the following errors:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin

** (LCVTrial_CppOpenCV:1914): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(LCVTrial_CppOpenCV:1914): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'

(LCVTrial_CppOpenCV:1914): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(LCVTrial_CppOpenCV:1914): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable'

(LCVTrial_CppOpenCV:1914): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

(LCVTrial_CppOpenCV:1914): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(LCVTrial_CppOpenCV:1914): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(LCVTrial_CppOpenCV:1914): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
```

No errors are shown when running to a remote display.

I made a "stripped down" version of the application with only the GUI, removing OpenCV, and it runs fine on the Pi's display.

Any ideas or direction on where to look / investigate would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

there are some missing libs on Raspi
try on raspi terminal

```
sudo apt-get install at-spi2-core
```

in /etc/environment add

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
```

and do not forget update gstreamer

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried that. It got rid of the "qt5ct" message and the DBus warning, but all the other errors still come up and the application hangs.

Also now, adding the gtk2 setting in /etc/environments makes it so I can't even run the application on the remote xserver. I get all the WARNING and CRITICAL errors from above along with "libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found" and "libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast".